# x86-64 Linux: Info on filesystem and type of a mounted partitions disappears

Tags: linux, mount, lsof

System x86-64 Slackware 15.0 based live Linux (Porteus 5.0.1)

At unpredictable times, info on **filesystem** and **type** of a mounted partitions disappears.

As normal user I see e.g. this:

```
rava@rava:/mnt/sdd3/tmp$ df -Tm .
Filesystem     Type 1M-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on
-              -      1873128 718566   1154447  39% /mnt/sdd3
rava@rava:/mnt/sdd3/tmp$ umount /mnt/sdd3
umount: /mnt/sdd3: not mounted.
rava@rava:/mnt/sdd3/tmp$
```

Clearly the assumption "/mnt/sdd3: not mounted" is wrong, because as root I get this:

```
root@rava:/# umount /mnt/sdd3
umount: /mnt/sdd3: target is busy.
root@rava:/# df -Tm /mnt/sdd3
Filesystem     Type 1M-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on
-              -      1873128 718566   1154447  39% /mnt/sdd3
root@rava:/#
```

The issue can be solved by exiting all programs that access the partition, in this case, /mnt/sdd3, and I would find all processes that do access it currently via

```
root@rava:/# lsof |grep sdd3
```

and mounting /mnt/sdd3 anew. But it is bothersome having to do that every time the info disappears.

The most bothersome on the disappearance of that info is that a generic

```
df -Tm
```

that should show all mounted partitions is omitting the partition that lost its *filesystem* and *type* info.
This happens to root as well as the normal user, only explicitly naming the partition shows its info as quoted above.

**Is there a way determining what is causing the *filesystem* and *type* info of a mounted partition to be lost, and a way preventing this loss of info?**

Comment: Does your non-root user have read access to `/etc/fstab` and `/etc/mtab` (which should be a symbolic link to `/proc/self/mounts` in most modern distributions)? Do you have something that would modify the permissions of these files, or the directories they're located in?

Comment: @telcoM /etc/fstab is 0644/-rw-r--r-- and owned by user root group root. Non-root can only read. /proc/self/mounts is 0444/-r--r--r-- user guest group users. AFAIK these are the permissions as they should be, or am I mistaken on that?

Comment: I could no longer edit my above comment, therefore a new one:  I wanted to add that /etc/mtab is a symbolic link to /proc/self/mounts

Comment: Yes, that looks correct. That, together with the fact that the information loss seems to happen with one partition only, eliminates the simplest possible cause for that kind of error. Now, what is the actual filesystem type of `/mnt/sdd3`, and are there any related error messages visible in `dmesg` output when it happens?

Comment: /etc/mtab states it is ext4, as does this warning: `dmesg | grep sdd3` gives this: `EXT4-fs (sdd3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)` and `EXT4-fs (sdd3): warning: checktime reached, running e2fsck is recommended` Aside from the warning recommending e2fsck no error messages are to be seen; could a recommended e2fsck really be the sole reason for the FS and type info to get lost?

Comment: The recommendation itself is a routine message at filesystem mount time, but an undetected error lurking within the filesystem because it's not been checked in a long time might certainly cause all kinds of strange behavior. Please unmount the filesystem and run `sudo e2fsck -C0 /dev/sdd3` (assuming that `/dev/sdd3` is the actual device that gets mounted at `/mnt/sdd3`). A filesystem check once in a while is a requirement for classic filesystem types like `ext4`.

Comment: If the time required to check the filesystem is an issue, consider placing the filesystem on a LVM volume and installing `e2scrub` to automatically perform the check in the background, or perhaps use a filesystem like XFS that has the routine checks built into the filesystem driver and automatically does them in the background.

Comment: Done, e2fsck did report nothing serious. It was the harddisk of a NAS where the NAS hardware failed but the drive is okay, so I am using it as conventional external drive. One thing of note might be that "Lost and Found" was missing, I let e2fsck create it.